# Crob job excluding some hours

Tags: cron, crontrigger

Currently I'm having two cronjobs as following,

> 0 */6 * * * root job1
>
> 0 */2 * * * root job2

I need to avoid running the job2 when job1 is running.
Is there a way to exclude the time (00 00 , 06 00 , etc . . ) from the job2 cron.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no exclusion syntax. Change job2 to:

```
0 2,4,8,10,14,16,20,22 * * * root job2
```